# Select timestamptz as UTC zulu string

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 9.5 I have a column of type timestamptz and if I just do a straight select I get a string like so:

```
2014-08-08 20:48:27.097971+00
```

What's the proper way to do the select so that the column output is a Zulu time string, like `20140808T204827Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exact output as you posted then:

```
SELECT  to_char(
            '2014-08-08 20:48:27.097971+00'::timestamptz,
            'YYYYMMDD"T"HH24MISS"Z"' );

     to_char
------------------
 20140808T204827Z
(1 row)
```

More about date/time formatting: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Maybe it should be noted that the timestamp as stored does not have any time zone associated. So it would be a better solution to add `AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/Zulu'` after the timestamp.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: not true, the `+00` part is about timezone.

Comment: @KrisoMagi no,  the 00 is just the client timezone.  The timestamptz type is actually just an absolute timestamp.

Comment: @RichardHuxton: correct, I was wrong. But isn't 'Etc/Zulu' same as UTC? According to pg_timezone_names: `Etc/Zulu | UTC    | 00:00:00   | f` so assuming server/client is by default UTC given solution should be ok. Still, I agree for being certain to get with correct timezone, then adding `AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/Zulu'` is better.